# Issues with using arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm learning how to do arrays and have been stuck on this project currently. I've attached what I have, but haven't been able to figure out where I'm going wrong as the programs just continues to repeat without ending on the answer I need.

It's supposed to allow the user to enter 20 numbers, then display each number and its difference from the numeric average of the numbers entered. Part 2 of the assignment is to modify it so the user can enter and amount of numbers up to 20 until a sentinel value is entered.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    const int SIZE = 12;
    int numbers[12] = { 0 };
    int value = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int total = 0;
    int average = 0;
    int diffFromAvg = 0;
    int SENTINEL = -1;

    cout << "Please enter a positive number: " << endl;
    cin >> value;

    while ((counter < SIZE) && (value != SENTINEL))
    {
        total = total + value;
        numbers[counter] = value;
        counter = counter + 1;

        if (counter != SIZE) {
            cout << "Please enter a positive number: " << endl;
            cin >> value;
        }
        if (counter > 0) {
            average = total / counter;
            for (int i = 0; i <= SIZE; i--)
            {
                diffFromAvg = numbers[i] - average;
                cout << "Number[i]: " << numbers[i] << " Difference from Average is " <<
                    diffFromAvg << endl;
            }
        }
        else {
            cout << "Processing incomplete. No values in the array." << endl;
        }
    }

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I recommend using a debugger.

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i<=SIZE; i--)` Doesn't look right for 2 reasons: 1) you are iterating in the opposite direction, invoking undefined behavior in doing so (shouldn't it be `i++`?) 2) Even if it were `i++`, you would still read past the end of the array, due to condition being `<=SIZE`, which would invoke undefined behavior as well. Too lazy to check if this is the only problem in the code, so I'll leave it as a comment :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answer is equally good.  I kept your while() loop, but made a few changes. It is wise to separate your processing a little more.  This could be broken up into smaller functions

```c++
   #include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int SIZE = 12;
    int numbers[12];
    int value = 0;
    int index;
    int SENTINEL = -1;

    index = 0;  // initialize here so you keep track of it
    while ((index < SIZE) && (value != SENTINEL)) {

        cout << "Please enter a positive number: " << endl;
        cin >> value;

        numbers[index] = value;

        index++; // increment index after assigning the array value
    }

    // Calculate the average
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        total += numbers[i];
    };
    int average = total / SIZE;

    cout << "Average is: " << average << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        int diffFromAvg = numbers[i] - average;
        cout << "Number[i]: " << numbers[i]
             << " Difference from Average is "
             << diffFromAvg << endl;
    }

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works like it should. Is there a way to get to work without having the beginning "int Average" part? I have to follow a pseudocode and this differs from it.

Comment: @hal, I have moved the "int average" down lower.  Is that sufficient?  If not, be more detailed as what you need for the "format".

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond, but this is what I have to follow:

Comment: // Start
//     Declarations
//         num SIZE = 12
//         num numbers[SIZE]
//         num value = 0
//         num counter = 0
//         num total = 0
//         num average = 0
//         num diffFromAvg = 0
//         num  SENTINEL = -1
//
//     output "Please enter a positive number: "
//     input value
//     while ((counter < SIZE) AND (value <> SENTINEL) )
//       total = total + value
//       numbers[counter] = value
//       counter = counter + 1

Comment: //       if (counter <> SIZE)
//         output "Please enter a positive number: "
//         input value
//       endif
//     endwhile
//
//     if (counter > 0) then
//       average = total/counter
//       for i = 0 to counter - 1
//         diffFromAvg = numbers[i] - average
//         output "Number[",i,"]: ",numbers[i]," Difference from Average is 
",diffFromAvg
//       endfor
//     else
//       output "Processing incomplete. No values in the array."
//     endif
// Stop

Comment: I've updated the answer to remove the int ..average function.  Beyond that, you will need to figure this out.  Please accept the answer if this is one that works for you.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you follow the [IPO model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPO_model):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    constexpr std::size_t max_numbers{ 20 };
    constexpr int sentinel{ -1 };

    int numbers[max_numbers];
    std::size_t num_count{};

    int sum{};

    // input:
    for (int current_value;
         num_count < max_numbers && std::cout << "Please enter a positive number: " &&
         (std::cin >> current_value) && current_value != sentinel;
         ++num_count)
    {
        numbers[num_count] = current_value;
        sum += current_value;
    }

    // proccess:
    if (!num_count) {
        std::cerr << "No input.\n\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    auto mean{ sum / static_cast<double>(num_count) };

    // output:
    std::cout.put('\n');
    for (std::size_t i{}; i < num_count; ++i)
    {
        auto distance_to_mean{ numbers[i] - mean };
        std::cout << "Number " << std::setw(2) << i + 1 << ": " << std::setw(5) << numbers[i]
                  << '\t' << std::setw(5) << std::fixed << distance_to_mean << '\n';
    }
    std::cout.put('\n');
}
```